# Circle Progress Gradient Border in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I've been trying to do this for hours and I'm not succeeding at all.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

**Created by Designer:**

[image: Created by designer]

**Created by me:**

[image: Created by me]

---

**How is my code:**

```dart
class CircularArc extends StatelessWidget {
  const CircularArc({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 55,
      height: 55,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: const Color(0xFF8BC26A).withOpacity(0.3),
            blurRadius: 18.94,
          ),
          BoxShadow(
            color: const Color(0xFF54A99A).withOpacity(0.3),
            blurRadius: 18.94,
          )
        ],
        gradient: const LinearGradient(
          colors: [
            Color(0xFF8BC26A),
            Color(0xFF54A99A)
          ],
          begin: Alignment.centerLeft
        ),
      ),
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.black,
          shape: BoxShape.circle
        ),
        child: Image.asset('images/user.png'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

*I wanted this gradient to grow as a percentage of progress.*

Comment: `gradient to grow as a percentage of progress` means any effect on color except increasing progress value?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh just increase progress and circle size with gradient grow

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63615001/how-to-create-gradient-progress-indicator-like-this

Answer (score 1):

I am using `CustomPainter` to draw on UI, you can adjust gradient, I'm having some trouble with it. And you can duplicate the widget with `Stack` with opacity for glow effect.

Run on [dartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=6a3235b6f8806c391e35eb7c44e8e703).

[image]

```dart
SizedBox(
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  child: CustomPaint(
    size: const Size(200, 200), // no effect while adding child
    painter: CircularPaint(
      progressValue: sliderValue, //[0-1]
    ),
    child: const Center(
      child: Icon(
        Icons.umbrella,
        size: 56,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

**Paint class**

```dart
import 'dart:math' as math;
///....
double deg2rad(double deg) => deg * math.pi / 180;

class CircularPaint extends CustomPainter {
  /// ring/border thickness, default  it will be 8px [borderThickness].
  final double borderThickness;
  final double progressValue;

  CircularPaint({
    this.borderThickness = 8.0,
    required this.progressValue,
  });
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Offset center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

    final rect =
        Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: size.width, height: size.height);

    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.grey.withOpacity(.3)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = borderThickness;

    //grey background
    canvas.drawArc(
      rect,
      deg2rad(0),
      deg2rad(360),
      false,
      paint,
    );

    Paint progressBarPaint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = borderThickness
      ..shader = const LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
        end: Alignment.centerRight,
        colors: [
          Colors.purple,
          Colors.orange,
          Colors.green,
          Colors.deepOrange,
        ],
      ).createShader(rect);
    canvas.drawArc(
      rect,
      deg2rad(-90),
      deg2rad(360 * progressValue),
      false,
      progressBarPaint,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, works perfectly! just what i wanted